# RestEasy-Links: javax.el-3.0.0.jar is not loaded during the deployment on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, resteasy

im going to write a little rest service and facing a issue when it comes to the link injection.

I´m using `resteasy 3.0.7.Final` and `resteasy-links 3.0.7.Final`. When i deploy the application to Tomcat (7.0.59) the log shows the following information:

```
INFORMATION: validateJarFile(/Users/user/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/
org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/jaxrs-wnck/WEB-INF/lib/javax.el-3.0.0.jar)
- jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class:
javax/el/Expression.class
Apr 04, 2015 6:29:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile

INFORMATION: validateJarFile(/Users/user/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.
server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/jaxrs-wnck/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar)
- jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class:
javax/el/Expression.class
```

The service starts but when im requesting a resource which performs a link  injection into the
`RESTServiceDiscovery` field, a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.StandardELContext` is thrown.

-
thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tomcat 7, Expression Language API specification version is 2.2 and `StandardELContext` is in version 3.0.

From [Servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf):

> As described in the Java EE license agreement, servlet containers that
>   are not part of a Java EE product should not allow the application to
>   override Java SE platform classes, such as those in the java.* and
>   javax.* namespaces, that Java SE does not allow to be modified.

So, you can:

- update to tomcat 8;
- deploy your application in a Java EE container, which allow the application to override;
- use an older version of rest easy (3.0.5.Final should work);

Comment: I have this same problem on CentOS Tomcat 7 (I think it is the same problem) and was misled by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600981/el-api-1-0-jar-jar-not-loaded-offending-class-javax-el-expression-class which has no answer. Mr. Cesar's answer helped me find the solution.

Comment: When I marked javax.el-api version 3.0.0 as "provided" in my POM the problem went away - I hope this helps anyone with the same problem. However I think that updating to TC 8 is a better solution if it allows my app libs to override the TC libs. Strangely I had no problem deploying to TC 7 in Eclipse on my Mac, but when I deployed to TC 7 on CentOS I got the exact conflict stated in the aforementioned post.